# Vue pages not loading on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am currently developing a website and I have been using google chrome to view the page in. Now I decided to check it out on Microsoft Edge but Vue-Router doesnt seem to want to load any components. I get the following error:

[image: Following error:]

Anyone have any idea's on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Did you find a fix? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I have not @Tom

Comment: Just started a bounty on my question - hopefully someone can help us out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578878/add-proposal-object-rest-spread-plugin-to-babel-config-js-to-fix-microsoft-edg BTW: I read that Microsoft Edge is switching to Chromium next year. That should fix those issues as well.

Comment: @Tom yeah, u can already install a beta of it. Iv been using it for the past couple of months, its pretty decent :)