# Add "proposal-object-rest-spread" plugin to babel.config.js to fix Microsoft Edge error SCRIPT1028

Tags: vue.js, plugins, config, microsoft-edge, babeljs

**EDIT: This issue seems to be fixed with the new beta of Microsoft Edge Chromium. (January 18, 2020)**

I need to add this [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread) to **babel.config.js** to get rid of the Microsoft **Edge** Browser error

> SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

I installed the latest packages and added them to package.json. 
Below is what I tried but it doesn't transform the code after running **npm run build**:

***babel.config.js***

```
require("@babel/core").transform("code", {});

module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/app"],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
};
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-flickity": "^1.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "sass": "^1.17.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

How to setup the Babel plugin to transform the code correctly?

EDIT: Error Screenshot - EDGE INSIDER 18 points to this piece of code:
[image: Error: EDGE INSIDER 18 points to this piece of code.]

Comment: Perhaps it is related other dependencies, try to use the following code to update all of the dependencies: `$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ ncu -u
$ npm install `

Comment: have you solved this issue? in positive case could you please update to show to to use babel configuration? tks

Comment: @Prisco Didn't solve it. I'm still looking for a fix

Comment: I have the same exact issue on Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 but I don't see the SCRIPT1028 error using the Beta version 83.0.478.37. I'm wondering if there is an actual fix or workaround though for older versions of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

since I cannot try out the code that you are dealing with to check, I would suggest to use the following babel config as mentioned in the library config:

```
  plugins: [["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread", { "loose": true, "useBuiltIns": true }]]
```

Comment: Your example is for .babelrc and didn't work for babel.config.js. How to rewrite it for babel.config.js?

Answer (score 0):

`babel.config.js` should export a [function](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#babelconfigjs) and should be at the root of your project.

Your configuration should be similar to this

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);

    const presets = ['@vue/app'];
    const plugins = ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'];
    // Or try this
    // const plugins = [['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread', { loose: true, useBuiltIns: true }]];

    return {
        presets,
        plugins,
    };
};
```

Comment: I tried both examples in "Edge" and "Edge Insider" but the error `SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number` still remains. It works in Chrome/Firefox. "EdgeInsider" (the upcoming Edge Browser) is based on Chromium, any ideas why this error comes up?

Comment: Interesting. Can you share minimal repro or is your project open source? It would be helpful to debug better.

Comment: I will upload a minimal repro later. BTW: This is the piece of code that causes the error in EDGE INSIDER 18: https://imgur.com/a/yLxLQUt (screenshot)

Comment: Okay. Looks like its not transforming `...` syntax. Hard to debug without repro 